# Test with SpyBean failing only in Gitlab pipeline

Tags: java, mocking, gitlab, mockito, gitlab-ci

My project has two test suites which both mock the same bean by using the `@SpyBean` annotation. Locally this works fine, but when the tests are run in my Gitlab pipeline an exception is thrown that can only be thrown when the actual, original bean is called (rather than the mocked one). As if one of the SpyBean annotations was never processed. It doesn't always throw this exception, sometimes re-running the pipeline makes it work again.

It turns out that the reason it fails in the pipeline but not locally is that the tests are ran in inverse order in the pipeline, and it looks like one test suite affects the other one but not the other way round. Currently I fixed this by using the `ClassOrderer` functionality in the new version of JUnit and set `junit.jupiter.testclass.order.default=<my custom class orderer class>`. This way I enforce an order.

It would be nice to find some actual fix though, to avoid such issues in the future. Here's relevant code :

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public abstract class BatchTaskTest {

    @Autowired
    protected QueueService queueService;

}
```

This test suite works fine if ran first, it fails if ran last :

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_CLASS)
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
public class ResponseTaskHappyFlowTest extends BatchTaskTest {

    @SpyBean 
    private MyServiceRetryableClient myServiceClient;

    protected void testHappyFlow(String taskFileName, String xmlFileName) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ...
        mockGetMyServiceDocument(invocation -> {
            ... // various assertions
        });
        queueAndWaitForNewTask(task); // this indirectly causes my service to be called
    }

}
```

The second test suite :

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_CLASS)
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
public class ResponseTaskUnhappyFlowTest extends BatchTaskTest {

    @SpyBean 
    private MyServiceRetryableClient myServiceClient;

    ... // very basic tests, not even necessary to cause the fail

}
```